# CSS : Put a border on an entire article excluding the title

Tags: css, border

I need to put a border (or a decorative line, doesn't matter) on the left of an article, excluding the title.
It's a bit hard to explain but easier to draw :

```
H2 Title
 | paragraph : Iorem impsum
 | Dolor sit amet,
 | etc, etc.
```

The H2 title is in the article, and the content of the article is indented (1 indent).
The only way i've found is this horrible thing (i'm basically placing the title over the border with a white background to override it) :

```
article
{
    position: relative;
    left: 25px;
    border-left: 1px dotted grey; 
}

article h2
{
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    left:-25px;
}
```

Which works, but i'm not too fond of using relative positioning for such a small change.
So, is there a more convenient way of doing it, set aside moving the title out of the article ?

Comment: There are MANY ways to do this, Tai's answer is correct (although you should always try to use classes instead of IDs). What shocks me is your "I'm not too fond of using relative positioning for such a small change". You use what you need to use, and while you didn't need this at all, it's one of the approaches (for example: article>relative article h2>absolute), which in your case is overboard, but seeing you don't know much about CSS positioning, would have hep you to understand it by live example

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to indent and border some text- something like this?

```css
#bordered{
  border-left: 1px dotted grey;
  margin-left: 1em
}
```

```html
<h1>title</h1>
<p id="bordered">bordered</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just separate the two with divs and style as needed.

Answer (score -1):

Can you add a wrapper style within the article, after the H2?

HTML:

```
<article>
    <h2>Iorem impsum</h2>

    <div class="wrap">
        <p>Dolor sit amet, etc, etc.</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
article {
    position: relative;
}
article h2 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
article .wrap {
    border: 1px dotted grey;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jazztorbs/t13sna84/